# How to unmerge lists within a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out how to unmerge a bunch of lists from within a list. For example, from

```
parent_list = [ [a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i] ]
```

to

```
child_list1 = [a, b, c]
child_list2 = [d, e, f]
child_list3 = [g, h, i]
```

Comment: Do you know at coding time how many sublists there will be?

Comment: @user3421111:  Numbered variable names (`name1`, `name2`, etc) are a code-smell that usually indicates an incorrect approach.  Why do you need names for the sublists?

Comment: Why don't you just use `parent_list[i]`?

Answer (score 6):

Use [unpacking](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html):

```
>>> parent_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
>>> child_list1, child_list2, child_list3 = parent_list
>>> child_list1
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> child_list2
['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> child_list3
['g', 'h', 'i']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
child_list1, child_list2, child_list3 = parent_list
```